# When I run ms-settings:system I get a pop up with text "ms-settings:system The media is write protected"

Tags: windows-10, default-settings

I ran the ms-settings:system from Windows 10 System Internals procexp.exe as Administrator, and I got a pop up with the text "ms-settings:system The media is write protected"

UPDATE: I changed the User Access Control to its lowest level, and I continue to the same pop up.

What does it mean?

Thx

Comment: Getting the syntax help. In an elevated command prompt `start ms-settings:\\system`.

Comment: After I typed start ms-settings:\\system in cmd as administrator I got the same pop up.

Comment: UPDATE: the pop up I referred to above came up after a window opened, it had a cog image and look like the ones that appeared before. So I assumed the command had executed... but just a few seconds ago, I got output "Access is denied" in the command window. Does this this help?